# Laravel 10 Maatwebsite\Excel how to import data without header columns?

Tags: excel, laravel

Laravel 10 Maatwebsite\Excel how to import data without header columns?

Given Laravel 10 laravel-excel - "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.48",

Lots of xls, csv... files with different data structure. The task is to load them into a temporary table ( JSON ), so that the user selects columns - from where to load something.

Problem: Not all files have column headers. I don't know how to make laravel-excel read a file like: 'A' =>'date' 'B' => 'data2' .. 'A' => 'date' 'B' => 'data2'

There is an idea - to consider headings and then to replace them. But I want something more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try below code.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;

class YourClassName implements ToModel, WithStartRow
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function startRow(): int
    {
       return 2;
    }
}
```